# Using Android's Google Sheets, how can an entire column of URLs be activated into hyperlinks

Tags: android, google-sheets, indexing, hyperlink, multiple-columns

I am using Android's Google Sheets mobile app.
I've already conducted searches here and online to no avail. The search terms together all muddle the results.

**Objective A**

My column (E2:E113) is populated with inactive URLs. I want to activate them all in a single motion.

**Attempts:**

1. I tried applying =HYPERLINK(E2:E113) into a cell in an open column (F), but that only activated the first cell (E2).
2. There seems to be no option to attempt that same formula into an equal number of cells in an open column; attempting a copy of that exact formula into an open range of F2:F113 is not an optionable method.
3. An attempt at applying that formula to the original range only results in a #REF! error into the first cell.

What is the answer? Is this possible with the mobile app?

**Objective B**

If possible, after activation of the entire column of URLs into hyperlinks, I want to open that entire range of links into browser tabs. That's my ultimate objective here. Is this possible with Android Sheets?

Thank you, in advance, for helping me understand this.

Comment: Try to put this formula in your open column 'F'- `Arrayformula(HYPERLINK(E2:E113))`, you can use `Arrayformula(HYPERLINK(E2:E))` if you want to keep the range dynamic

Comment: I think that worked to signal each cell to offer an "Open in [browser]" hover menu. I ended up going a different route by copying the column range over to a Docs page. With the links listed there, I entered a paragraph space between each link to activate each one. Then I clicked on each and every one to open them into Firefox, where I then saved them all together as a Collection, which was my ultimate goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(HYPERLINK(E2:E113))
```

Comment: Yes! That is EXACTLY the precise solution I want. You are a god among spreadsheet rookies, particularly me. Thank you!